# exporting datagridview to textfile with syntax error for converting money to string format

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to convert money to string like claim amount = 100.00 should be converted to 0010000
Court fees = 15 converted to 01500 and solictors fee  = 00000(always the same number)
 and total amount = 115  converted to 00011500. I dont how to convert these to zeros in the first place.

```
string value = Convert.ToString(ReturnValue);
```

Gives output :it is showing as 100.0000

can you help me where i am going wrong.

I tried this **but still  the same result**. it is an sql query

```
" bat.PCN_Charge *100 ".ToString().PadLeft(7, '0') +
",[Court Fee] *100 ".ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') +
",[Solictors Fees] *100 ".ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') +  
", (bat.PCN_Charge + [Court Fee]) *100".ToString().PadLeft(8, '0')  +
```

My results are like these  `10000.0000  1500    0   11500.0000`

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to do? The first question was getting `0010000` instead of getting `100.0000`. I provided the solution for that. Now the code you pasted in your edit is not clear to me. What you can do is, get the normal value from your database by usual query. Then use my code and convert them to desired result.

Comment: sorry iqbal for late reply.... bat.PCN_Charge,[Court Fee] etc are columns in sql table. i am   using your answer like this  but this gives me an errorr can you look at this please  `"(bat.PCN_Charge)".string.Format("{0:0000000}", ReturnValue * 100) +`

Comment: Not like that, give me the full query. Or try to use ` double courtFee = bat.PCN_Charge,[Court Fee].Value as double; string strcourtFee = string.Format("{0:0000000}, courtFee * 100); // here your desire value will be in strcourtFee variable.`

Answer (score 0):

If you know your string should always have a length of seven, you can first calculate the plain int-value, then use:

```
value.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0')

// Example
var numericValue = 100.00;
var intValue = numericValue * 100; // 10000
var paddedResult = intValue.ToString().PadLeft(7, '0'); // 0010000
```

Alternatively, you can find lot's of info about [padding numbers with zero here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

yes very simple

First multiply by `100` to override the decimal point.
Second use `Format` instead of `convert`

Try this

```
string value = string.Format("{0:0000000}", ReturnValue * 100);
```

Happy Coding

:)